# ¿Quitar el marcado de consultas MySQL en PHPStorm?

Tags: php, ide

¿Cómo puedo quitar el marcado de las consultas MySQL en PHPStorm? Solo me interesa el resaltado de sintaxis, no me gusta que marque las consultas con ese color.

[image: Marcado de consulta MySQL]

Saludos y gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¡Gracias Marcos!

Comment: He agregado creado una respuesta a tu pregunta, si la misma es acertada, considera marcarla como tal y/o votarla.

Answer (score 2):

Tenes que ir a:

- *Windows/Linux*: `File > Settings > Editor >`[`Language Injections`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/language-injection-settings-dialog-sql-type-injection.html)
- macOS: `PhpStorm > Preferences > Editor >`[`Language Injections`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/language-injection-settings-dialog-sql-type-injection.html)

y desactivar las reglas que no te gusten.

Otra opción es desactivar el `plugin SQL/database`.